# Why is Python's 'len' function exaggerating the length of an array of bytes?

Tags: python

I'm developping a Python script on Windows in Visual Studio Code using Don Jayamanne's Python extension. Here is the content of my 'watch' debug window:

[image: VSCode screenshot]

The length of the byte array someBytes is 20, but Python's len function makes it 77. Why?

The array is generated thus:

```
def sendTouchDown(ble):
    message = bytes([0x01, 0x68, 0x03, 0x39, 0x05, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF])
    if ble:
        sendMuxBle(message)
    else:
        sendMuxRfcomm(message)
```

And then its length measured thus:

```
def sendMuxRfcomm(someBytes):
    crc = 0xFFFF
    for i in range(0, len(someBytes), 2):
```

Comment: Because `someBytes` is a string representation of the array of bytes.

Comment: `someBytes[0] = '['` no doubt…

Comment: That would explain why my code's going mad!

Comment: @dumbledad: Ahah. It can be very convenient for a string to be considered automatically as an iterator of chars, it can hide bugs though if you expect a list and not a string.

Comment: (Removed my answer because it no longer applied after seeing the code in the latest edit)

Comment: What version of Python is this? On Python 3.6, everything seems right, the length of the `bytes`'ed list is `20`, which looks ok.

Comment: Good call @Right-leg, I'd swapped development machine and hadn't spotted that the original was 3.6.0 but the one with the problems was 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like one of those weird things of Python 2 that was fixed in Python 3.

The `bytes` constructor will take any non-string passed into it and convert it to a string.  Hence your statement is logically equivalent to this:

```
thelist = [0x01, 0x68, 0x03, 0x39, 0x05, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF]
message = bytes(str(thelist))
```

Create a byte literal like this instead:

```
message = b'\x01\x68\x03\x39\x05\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF'
```

I went back and read the PEP for bytes when it was proposed for Python 2.6:

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0358/

It clearly says this about the constructor:

The initializer argument can be a string (in 2.6, either str or unicode), an **iterable of integers**, or a single integer.

Maybe this is a bug in Python.  Or there's something Pythonic between lists and strings I'm missing here.

Comment: Yep - I was inadvertently swapping between development machines with one on 3.6 and one on 2.7